# DB replication, each db their own distributor or use a single distributor?

Tags: sql, replication

this may be a simple question for most but I am a bit confused and could use guidance, I am not a DBA, however I need to present out case for servers to our DBA's

I am looking to set up replication across multiple servers however each server will only publish a subset of the data...

I planed on having the main server publish all downstream data to all subscribers acting as its own distributor.

the main server will also subscribe to all of its downstream servers(immediately bellow it) to consolidate the results making a complete dataset

the second level servers will subscribe to the main server to receive all downstream information and then will  publish their contents filtered for the subscribers so each subscriber only has the information it needs to operate efficiently. it will act as its own distributor

and the second level servers will publish a second set of tables for upstream replication to be consolidated at main

the bottom level is on a station to station basis so we will be using express to subscribe and receive their downstream specific information, we will then use code to write up from the express to second level database as express does not support publications.

using this style, is there any point/benefit to using a single server as distributor, or is it even possible to use a single distributor as all information will be filtered differently (one second level server may be publishing 10-12 different sets of data for station specific operations not counting the upstream publication)

am I just way off base with my replication... I ran tests here setting up everything to verify functionality, and desired outcome and everything seems to be working as designed...

Comment: Probably the DBA forum (http://dba.stackexchange.com/) can help you better on this...

Comment: @SoulTrain thanks I will move over there,